# Why does a Django forms.TextField take up so much space, even when the text input area is small?

Tags: html, css, django

I'm creating a Django form and when I change from a TextInput to a TextArea the html/css requires a lot more spacing around the element, here it is with TextArea:
[image]

and here it is with a TextInput:

[image]

I'm using Bulma css framework. and everything I've tried to make the TextField "fit" to use the area that is available has failed. The bulma column has display: flex, which cannot be altered either.

How can I use the textarea while keeping a "tight" layout?

edit: putting fixed height on the div works, but then it loses all responsibility, and the layout does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically

```
 The <input> tag specifies an input field where the user can enter data. 

 and

 The <textarea> tag defines a multi-line text input control.
```

this is basic difference and that why it take to much space

you can try this

```
 class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = MyModel
     widgets = {
          'yourtextarea': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':15}),
        }
```